# Capture RRC Messages using Libpcap on android

Tags: android, network-programming, wireless, pcap, libpcap

I have compiled the libpcap for android and using this library i have written a tool which is capturing all the packets transferred over network. Now i need to get all the RRC messages sent/recieved over network, but i don't know how to do this. Is there any method/API available to capture the RRC messages using Libcap?

Comment: By "RRC messages" do you mean [mobile phone Radio Resource Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Resource_Control) messages?

Answer (score 0):

RRC messages can be seen and captured on the radio interface level and most of the radio chip communication is vendor specific and even through RRC follows the ASN.1 format, You may not be able to capture the RRC message as that means you are acting like a "man in the middle" i.e. between your device and the live network.

To capture the RRC message you will need to create a dummy RRC entity that represent the network to your device and then you use that Network Server/Entity to capture and receive the RRC message. You will need a specific test sim for those. You can google and get a test sim that will allow y